# Undefined symbol: _SKAdNetworkCoarseConversionValueMedium

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart

mac os :12.5
xcode version :13.3

when i run project in xcode. every time show this error.

Undefined symbol: _SKAdNetworkCoarseConversionValueLow
Undefined symbol: _SKAdNetworkCoarseConversionValueHigh
Undefined symbol: _SKAdNetworkCoarseConversionValueMedium

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.